# servicestack and Serilog not working properly

Tags: servicestack, serilog

I have not been able to successfully implemented logging in service stack. I posted here and on serilog GIT. The Serilog team believes it is a service stack issue. If you want access to my project let me know.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1267

[Cannot deconstruct object into Json serilog and Servicestack IReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965943/cannot-deconstruct-object-into-json-serilog-and-servicestack-ireturn)

I also am calling the service from my base class

```
public class ServiceBase: Service
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Examples
        /// ILog.Debug(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        /// ILog.Info(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        /// ILog.Warn(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        /// ILog.Error(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        /// ILog.Fatal(Exception ex, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        /// ILog.ForContext(Type type)
        /// ILog.ForContext<T>()
        /// ILog.ForContext(ILogEventEnricher enricher)
        /// ILog.ForContext(IEnumerable<ILogEventEnricher> enrichers)
        /// ILog.ForContext(string propertyName, object value, bool destructureObjects = false)
        /// </summary>
        public ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ServiceBase));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. You nee to initialize the logger after `app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost {AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)});`

[Answer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1267)